# How does operator precedence and typecasting work here

Tags: c

Okay, so I'm writing working on pointers here and I'm not sure how this piece of code works.

```
typedef struct linkedlist {
    void *obj;
    struct linkedlist *next;
} linkedlist;
linkedlist *p;

//some code here

int *newpointer = (*(int *)(p->next)->obj); //code chunk in question
```

If I need to typecast the void pointer 'obj' in the struct pointed to by p->next (assume it already exists) and copy it to 'newpointer' int pointer, am I doing it right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Did you consult your compiler about whether it is OK with what you've done?  What about your debugger?  Why are you storing a `void *` instead of an `int *`?  Why are you dual-tagging this with C and C++?  This looks more like C code than C++ because of the `typedef` which C++ really doesn't need.  Assigning an `int` to an `int *` should generate a compilation warning.

Comment: Hello Jon, I just read the about page. I see what I did there. It's just that I have a linked list with elements that are required to point to any data type. This means that I must use a void pointer to allow for easy type-casting. I know that void typecasting is bad. It's just that the design specs are like this. I am also still getting to grips with the debugger. Will be more diligent from now on.

Comment: Sometimes, designs are given, for better or worse.  Please remember not to dual tag with C and C++.  Other than that, if you've learned, that's good; that's what we're here for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int *newpointer = (*(int *)(p->next)->obj); //code chunk in question
```

> If I need to typecast the void pointer 'obj' in the struct pointed to by p->next (assume it already exists) and copy it to 'newpointer' int pointer, am I doing it right?

No. The compiler would have told you that. You don't need all those parentheses either:

```
int *newpointer = (int *)p->next->obj;
```

Comment: I would +1 if I could (Newbie here). I really should pay more attention to those compiler messages.

Comment: @solaremperor You should pay *total* attention to them. A well written program won't generate any compiler messages at all. Track down every one you get, and ask yourself why you caused it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to initialize the pointer `newpointer` with the *dereferenced* value of the casted pointer which is an error. Gcc says:

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'

Remove the call to the dereference operator:

```
int *newpointer = (int*) p->next->obj; // Also stripped unnecessary parentheses.
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, the typecast operator has lower precedence than the member access operators. Hence,

```
(int*)p->next->obj = (int*)(p->next->obj) = (int*)((p->next)->obj)
```

If the member access operators were of higher precedence, you would use:

```
int *newpointer = (int*)(p->next->obj);
```

Since they are not, you can omit all the paratheses and use:

```
int *newpointer = (int*)p->next->obj;
```